# SqlBulkCopy - mirroring failed :(

Tags: sql, bulk, mirroring

I've optimized my import application and I broke my mirroring, I'm pretty sure it's because of it. I get this error and I cannot resume it.

remote mirroring partner for database 'foo', encountered error 3624, status 1, severity 20. Database mirroring has been suspended.  Resolve the error on the remote server and resume mirroring, or remove mirroring and re-establish the mirror server instance.

How can I use SqlBulkCopy with mirroring?

Answer (score 0):

Please open a [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer) issue, attach any ERRORLOG and any dump from MSSQL\LOG*.mdmp (check both principal and mirror's location), the corrupted MDF and LDF files from the mirror.

And also make sure you have both systems patched with most recent CUs. For instance there is know issue with SQL Server 2008 fixed in CU10/SP1 and CU1/SP2: [FIX: An error message may occur when you run a "BULK INSERT" query on a database that uses the "BULK_LOGGED" or "SIMPLE" recovery model in SQL Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2297709) (although this is not your issue, since you must have full recovery mode for mirroring).

Comment: I've found this, but I have to wait for next major version? :-(( http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/412955/sql-database-mirroring-suspended-after-error-1453-severity-16-state-1-on-principal-and-sql-server-assertion-file-loglock-cpp-line-796-failed-assertion-result-lck-ok-on-mirror-server

Comment: "As a workaround, using CHECK_CONSTRAINTS hint for BCP will likely avoid this but also probably have a performance impact"